# Data Table elements becomes invisible when updating table using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

In my system I am using `data tables` to store the records for the convenience. I am using `PHP` and `Ajax` to load the records in the `HTML table`. Whenever I updated my `table` via operations it successfully updated without page refreshing but such `elements` becomes invisible including `filters`, `search box` and `pagination`. Just I want to `manually refresh` to visible those `elements`.

Here is my `HTML` code segments.

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <div class="card-block">                               
                            <div class="table-responsive" id="user_data">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Here is my `Ajax Query` codes

```
     /**---------Active A ROW ----------------*/
        $(document).on('click', '#rep1', function () {

            $("#activeid").attr('apt_id', $(this).attr('data_id'));

                $("#active_appointment").modal({ show: 'true' });

        });

        load_data();

         function load_data(){
              $.ajax({
              url: "sidebar/apt_table admin.php", // Url to which the request is send
              type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method

              success: function (data) {
              $('#user_data').html(data);

              }

          });
}

        $("#activeid").click(function () {

            var data_id = $("#activeid").attr('apt_id');

            $.ajax({
                data: { 'data_id': data_id, },
                type: "POST",
                url: "table/apt status.php",
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#success_mes').html(data);
                    $("#active_appointment").modal('hide');
                     load_data();


                }
            });

            setInterval(function () {
                $('#user_data').load("sidebar/apt_table admin.php").fadeIn("slow");
            }, 500);

        });

    </script>


<script>


     /**---------Cancel A ROW ----------------*/
      $(document).on('click', '#rep2', function () {

        $("#cancelid").attr('apt_id', $(this).attr('data_id'));

           $("#delete_appointment").modal({ show: 'true' });

    });

             load_data();

          function load_data(){
              $.ajax({
              url: "sidebar/apt_table admin.php", // Url to which the request is send
              type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method

              success: function (data) {
              $('#user_data').html(data);

          }

      });
    }

          $("#cancelid").click(function () {

            var data_id = $("#cancelid").attr('apt_id');

               $.ajax({
               data: { 'data_id1': data_id, },
               type: "POST",
               url: "table/apt status.php",

              success: function (data) {
            //   console.log(data);
            $('#success_mes').html(data);

            $("#delete_appointment").modal('hide');
          load_data();

        }
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        $('#user_data').load("sidebar/apt_table admin.php").fadeIn("slow");
    }, 500);

});

</script>
```

Here is my `apt_table admin.php`page.

```
        <table class="datatable table table-hover" >
                 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Appointment ID</th>
                            <th>Doctor Name</th>
                            <th>Specialization</th>         
                            <th>Patient Name</th>
                            <th>Fees</th>
                            <th>Appointment Date</th>
                            <th>Appointment Time</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                   </thead>
                       <tbody>
                         <tr>

                    <?php

       mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    try {

   $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hmsproject");
   $conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");

 } catch(Exception $e) {
   error_log($e->getMessage());
   exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand
 }

     $query="SELECT * FROM appointment as a,users as u  WHERE a.user_id= u.user_id ORDER BY apt_id DESC";   
     $results =mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if($results = mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0){
            while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($results) ) { 
            $apt_id= $row['user_id'];
            $user= $row['user_id']   ;
            ?>

                       <td><?php echo $row['apt_id']?> </td>
                       <td> <?php echo $row['doctor_name']?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo $row['specilization']?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo $row['patient_name']?></td>  
                       <td> <?php echo $row['fees']?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo $row['apt_date']?></td>
                       <td> <?php echo $row['apt_time']?></td>

                    <td>

                       <?php if($row['admin_status']=="0") {  ?>
                                <span class="custom-badge status-red">Cancel</span>
                                <?php } else if($row['admin_status']=="1") {    ?>
                                     <span class="custom-badge status-green">Active</span>
                                <?php  } else {   ?>
                                     <span class="custom-badge status-blue">Pending</span>

                                <?php } ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-right">
                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
                            <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="" data-toggle="modal" id="rep1" data_id=<?php echo $row['apt_id']  ?> data-target="#active_appointment"><i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Active</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="" data-toggle="modal" id="rep2" data_id=<?php echo $row['apt_id']  ?> data-target="#delete_appointment"><i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete</a>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                        <?php  }}} ?>

                          </tbody>
                     </table>
```

I don't know where I went wrong. Any help may highly appreciated.

Comment: did you see if you have some js errors in the console?

Comment: @GiacomoM No error occured